# i am facing error while building project in eclipse.make: *** [ril/src/Ril_dtmf.o] Error 1

Tags: makefile

I am facing an error while building project in eclipse.make: *** [ril/src/Ril_dtmf.o] Error 1

12:37:47 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project OpenCPU_SDK ****

```
"D:\\MC60_OpenCPU_GS3_SDK_V1.4_Eclipse\\make\\make.exe" all 
'Building file: ../ril/src/Ril_dtmf.c'
'Invoking: ARM Windows GCC C Compiler (Sourcery Lite Bare)'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -D__OCPU_COMPILER_GCC__ -D__CUSTOMER_CODE__ -I"C:\Program Files\CodeSourcery\Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI\arm-none-eabi\include" -I"D:\MC60_OpenCPU_GS3_SDK_V1.4_Eclipse\include" -I"D:\MC60_OpenCPU_GS3_SDK_V1.4_Eclipse\ril\inc" -I"D:\MC60_OpenCPU_GS3_SDK_V1.4_Eclipse\custom\config" -I"D:\MC60_OpenCPU_GS3_SDK_V1.4_Eclipse\custom\fota\inc" -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -c -fmessage-length=0 -mlong-calls -Wstrict-prototypes -MMD -MP -MF"ril/src/Ril_dtmf.d" -MT"ril/src/Ril_dtmf.d" -march=armv5te -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=soft -o "ril/src/Ril_dtmf.o" "../ril/src/Ril_dtmf.c"
'arm-none-eabi-gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [ril/src/Ril_dtmf.o] Error 1

12:37:48 Build Finished (took 1s.300ms)
```

Comment: Kindly edit your post with some formatting for readability and add more details on the steps followed to attract help.

Comment: This isn't a makefile problem.  The makefile is trying to compile your source code using a compiler named `arm-non-eabi-gcc` and you don't have that compiler installed, at least not in a directory on your path so it can't be found.  That's why you're getting an error _'arm-none-eabi-gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command_ etc.